# How to print N no. of elements of array each time on click

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 20 elements. I want to display first five elements on click of a button, then next five elements on another click, and so on. I would be grateful if you could help me with the code.

```js
var words = [20];
    var newArray = words.slice(0, 5);

    var words = ["day", "white", "go", "low", "wise", "up", "sit", "now", 
    "good", "grapes", "banana",
    "mango", "orange", "pears", "melon", "guava", "sunflower", "marigold", 
    "jasmine", "sunflower"];

    var x = "";

    var count = 0;

    function nextElems() {

        if (count < words.length) {

            var newArray = words.slice(0, 5);

            x += '<div>' + newArray + '</div>';

            document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = x;

            count = newArray;

        } else {

            count = 0;

            var secondArray = words.slice(5, 10);

            x += '<div>' + secondArray + '</div>';

            document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = x;

        }

        x = "";
     }
```

```html
    <button onclick="nextElems();"> Try </button>

    <div id="yes"> </div>
```

What I have tried displays the result two times correctly but not the third time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `words.slice(0, 5);` use `words.slice(count, count + 5);`

and instead of setting the `count` to `0`, increment it : `count += newArray.length;`

```js
var words = ["day", "white", "go", "low", "wise", "up", "sit", "now",
  "good", "grapes", "banana",
  "mango", "orange", "pears", "melon", "guava", "sunflower", "marigold",
  "jasmine", "sunflower"
];

var x = "";

var count = 0;

function nextElems() {
  if (count < words.length) {

    var newArray = words.slice(count, count + 5);

    x += '<div>' + newArray + '</div>';

    document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = x;

    count += newArray.length;    

  } else {

    count = 0;

    var secondArray = words.slice(count, count+5);

    x += '<div>' + secondArray + '</div>';

    document.getElementById('yes').innerHTML = x;

    count += 5;
  }

  x = "";

}
```

```html
<button onclick="nextElems()">Click</button>
<div id="yes"></div>
```

Comment: It's working fine only that it repeats first five elements at the end. Could you please suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick. You need to use the count variable as an argument to the slice method:

```js
var words = ["day", "white", "go", "low", "wise", "up", "sit", "now",
  "good", "grapes", "banana",
  "mango", "orange", "pears", "melon", "guava", "sunflower", "marigold",
  "jasmine", "sunflower"
];

var count = 0;

function nextElems() {

  var newArray = words.slice(count, count + 5);

  var x = document.createElement("div");
  x.innerHTML = newArray;

  document.getElementById('yes').appendChild(x);

  count += 5;

}
```

```html
<body>

  <button onclick="nextElems();"> Try </button>

  <div id="yes"> </div>

</body>
```